# BG Image Resizing

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a basic app with three views and the first view, the initial view, has an ImageView with a 320 x 460 (Ive also tried 320 x 480) image in it to serve as my background image for the view. The status bar is enabled. When I test the app on my phone the image resizes when the app first loads and eventually scales to fit the screen. What I am doing wrong with my image size? The initial view seems to 'jump' when the app first loads due to the image resizing and I dont want users to think there is an issue.

Here is my storyboard:

```
<objects>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="vni-Jh-JGC" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            <viewController id="gWY-GQ-C35" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="e8S-C8-ddz">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="320" height="460"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <imageView autoresizesSubviews="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" image="targetbg.png" id="s7d-M3-VIr">
                            <rect key="frame" x="-1" y="0.0" width="320" height="460"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                            <rect key="contentStretch" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                        </imageView>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="uF7-4u-0PX">
                            <rect key="frame" x="14" y="417" width="300" height="38"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="15"/>
                            <state key="normal" image="newsubmit.png">
                                <color key="titleColor" red="0.19607843459999999" green="0.30980393290000002" blue="0.52156865600000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                            </state>
                            <state key="highlighted">
                                <color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </state>
                            <connections>
                                <segue destination="2" kind="modal" id="Qkv-0y-8Sh"/>
                            </connections>
                        </button>
                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Blake Design Group" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumFontSize="10" id="Am2-mX-6Yv">
                            <rect key="frame" x="22" y="386" width="280" height="21"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="10"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="version 2.0" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" minimumFontSize="10" id="Buw-jD-jIs">
                            <rect key="frame" x="16" y="374" width="280" height="21"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="10"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
                <nil key="simulatedTopBarMetrics"/>
                <simulatedOrientationMetrics key="simulatedOrientationMetrics"/>
                <simulatedScreenMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            </viewController>
        </objects>
```

Comment: I created an image for the initial view. Its called targetbg.png

Comment: ok, and what's "image resizing"?

Comment: The image I have in the ImageView, targetbg.png, is resizing when the app loads. I am using the ImageView as the background for my Initial View.

Comment: It looks to be resizing about 20pxs or so. It looks to be rescaling more than anything. I think its 'trying' to fit the window. The image is the exact size as it should be so I dont know why its being resized/rescaled.

Comment: could you plz post some code or the storyboard in your question?

Comment: what's the frame size of your imageView?320 x 460?

Comment: I scaled the ImageView to fit the view on the stroyboard

Comment: show us the storyboard. otherwise it is difficult to analyze for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out and it was so simple. My launch image was 480 and my bg image was 460. This caused a brief overlap during loading and created what appeared to be a resize/rescale. Good lesson learned today.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are trying to create a splash screen
Here is what i did to get my splash screen working for iPhone and iPad

- I create a `UIView` (my splash View) not `UIViewController`
- First create a view with size 320*460
- Add a `UIImageView` to it, the imageView size is 320*460 and the y is set to -10
- The `UIImageView` and the container `UIView` has the resize mask set to 0 (no resize at all)
- the `UIImageView` has the content set to `center`
- in the `willMoveToSuperview` i have the following

  ```
  - (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
  {  
      BOOL isiPad = UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad == UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM();

      if(isiPad)
      {
          mainImage.image = [UIImage newImageFromResource:@"Default-Portrait~ipad.png"];            
      }
      else {
          mainImage.image = [UIImage newImageFromResource:@"Default"];                    
      }
  }
  ```
- now in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` i create this view and add it to the `self.window.rootViewController`

  ```
  [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:splashScreen];
  splashScreen.frame = self.window.rootViewController.view.bounds;
  splashScreen.autoresizingMask = AUTORESIZE_ALL;
  [splashScreen initialize];
  ```

This worked with me in both orientation and in iPad and iPhone,

Note: i used the same default.png images to create a splash

Comment: Im not creating an opening splash screen, my initial view has a button that goes to the next scene and the initial view is static until a button is pressed and the main app view is launched. Im working in the storyboard.